# Download audio from hidden audio tag

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-audio

I have a hidden html5 audio tag which has a source to play the audio from like below

```
<audio           
 hidden={true}
 <source src={Link to Audio} />
)}
</audio>
```

Now, since its hidden implementing `controls` do not display anything in UI, is there any way i can give a download button somewhere in the page, which on clicking downloads this audio.

Comment: An `<a>` to that audio file? PS: code looks like React, not HTML, pls mind your tags :-)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' My bad, updated tags, Could you please give an example, how can i do that?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Did like this  `<a href= {Link of Audio} download>Download</a>` but its navigating to that audio link first and from there, have to download by clicking on three dots icon. How to restrict this navigation and download directly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need the `<audio>` element, but you can download an audio file using the `<a>` element. You would do it like this:

```
<a href={linkToAudio} download>Download</a>
```

If you want to rename the downloaded file, you have to either rename it on the server or set the download attribute. An example:

```
<a href="/audio/song.mp3" download="downloaded_song.mp3">
    Download
</a>
```

This way, a user downloads an audio file named "song.mp3", but on the user's computer, it's saved as "downloaded_song.mp3".

Comment: Did like this  `<a href= {Link of Audio} download>Download</a>` but its navigating to that audio link first and from there, have to download by clicking on three dots icon. How to restrict this navigation and download directly?

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you're accessing the audio file through a cross-domain URL. To download it directly, the file must be hosted on the same domain as the parent site.

Comment: Thanks, Yes its cross domain, is there any way i can achieve this without redirect?

Comment: I am really not sure if it's possible without redirecting, but you can download the file to the server, like I already said, or keep the redirecting and just add `target="_blank"` attribute to the `<a>` element, so it's opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to my rep, but I don't think the `download` attribute works on the local machine alone. You need a server, it can be a local server on your machine but you can't access file via cross-domain. Meaning you can only download files from the origin site. If I had to guess why it's not working I would say either you're running your project without using a localhost server or you're trying to download files from another domain.

Comment: Chrome 65+ and Firefox only support same-origin download links, see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Yeah I figured he was running into a cross-cross origin error. I think chrome console tells you something like "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy". Only if I remembered I could have just told him to check his console first.